# Регулярные выражения - нужно что-то на подобии !=

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всем привет.
Мне нужно через регулярные выражения него найти строку, в которой есть указанное слово, но если в этой строке присутствует второе указанное слово - строка не подходит. Как такое написать?
Допустим если в строке есть "Hello" - то подходит
Но если там есть world - то даже при первом условии строка не подходит.
"Hello World" - не подходит
"Hello Max" - подходит
"Max Max" - не подходит
и т.п.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ich33m/1

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри конструкторы positive/neagtive lookahead (не знаю как на русский переводится)
По идее, они должны помочь с реализацией данной регулярки,хотя может я тебя неправильно понял, тогда попрошу немножко поподробнее расписать задачу

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).